# Joomla request variable values

Tags: joomla2.5

I have one question. I just want to be sure when i set some value in request variable whitout storing in database to not lost that value. This work fine but what if i come after 10 days that value stay or will be removed?

Ok simple example with option field:

```
<field name="bg" type="list" label="Set Background">
     <option value="1"> Black </option>
     <option value="2"> Red </option>
     <option value="3"> Green </option>
</field>
```

What i want say: When in administration i set in list Black background of current element is changed.

But what is confused? That value is not stored in databas.Can I lose the current value if it is not stored in the database.

This now work fine. But where joomla store that value? memory:memory?

I just want to be sure that the value does not change. Bcs is faster whitout database

Its simply make model

```
    // Get Background

public function getBackground()
{
    if(!isset($this->bg)) 
    {
        $bg = JFactory::getApplication()->input->get('bg', 1, 'INT');

        switch($bg)
        {
            case 1: $this->bg = 'black';  break;
            case 2: $this->bg = 'red'; break;
            case 3: $this->bg = 'green'; break;

            default: $this->bg = 'white';
        }

    }

    return $this->bg;
}
```

And view  render

```
<h1 style="background:<?php echo $this->bg;?>"> <?php echo $this->msg;?> </h1>
```

Comment: Do the options belong to a template parameter?